# Yocto, remove autotools from (userspace) package build process

Tags: makefile, package, autotools, yocto, building

Userspace package built for and along with root file system image of some embedded Linux-based system here (using Yocto project) apparently uses autotools - one can see Makefile.am's and configure.ac in package's sources. pkg-config or its successor seems to be used too (.pc.in is present), however out-of scope here.
Package in focus here does it this way (by involving autotools) as in the beginning of its development it was apparently the line of lowest resistance to copy and adopt build scripts from similar but already-existing package.
Actually autotools seem to be dispensable when building with Yocto, as Yocto build system meta data do specify target precisely enough for every target. For good reason standard build flow in Yocto is download, unpack, patch, configure, build,... with scan-and-detect-target-environment not included in this chain.

Now I wonder if it was good to streamline package's build process by removing autotools stage. I'm going to conduct it by proceeding in sequence of few steps starting with replacing .am file with real makefile. Question is if it will be sufficient enough to find env. variables defined and used in .am and .ac then transfer them to makefile? Remaining target-device specification should actually come from Yocto build system meta data. Possibly it will work this straightforward if to build package in scope of root file system image build. But how to ensure build environment provides complete target device specification when building only this package `bitbake package-name`?

Comment: If it ain't broke, don't fix it.  You stand to gain at most a minute or two less build time -- how much is that worth in terms of your own time and effort in performing and testing the (non-trivial) conversion?  Are you prepared to do it all over when you want to swap in a newer version of the package?

Answer (score 1):

Replacing autotools with a bare makefile isn't a trivial operation, as https://nibblestew.blogspot.co.uk/2017/12/a-simple-makefile-is-unicorn.html demonstrates nicely.

If you don't want to use autotools in your packages then alternatives such as Meson are generally faster.

Comment: You all 're right makefile generation then maintenance compliant to conventions used widely and meeting its goal widely might not be trivial task - this from info gathered from external as myself of zero experience and quite flat knowledge in matters. Concern rising idea was signaled in my initial post: when building with Yocto target device spec should be precisely set. Why then the step of build-and-run-time environment  analysis before configuring and building is needed (the primary goal of autotools in layman's understanding)? Are autools used widely for building packages with Yocto?

Comment: @Na13-c, The environment analysis step is *not* strictly needed.  In principle, you very well could prepare a Makefile directly.  But it is useful to perform the environment analysis anyway because *that's what the package's build system does*.  That saves you considerable time and effort vs. manually configuring the build.  It's not about Yocto.  It's about the packages you are building.

Comment: Feel free to populate the relevant site/ file in oe-core with the correct value for all of the tests that configure does to speed it up (so configure will just use the cached value from site, instead of running a test).  There are a lot of tests and the gain is marginal.